# Django rest framework - Field level validation in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer and I'm trying to add field level validation and I need to verify if some charfields of the serialize are empty or not, and if a boolean field is true or false.

I have this serializer but I never return an error even if Ficha_publicada is false

```
class PublicarSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    Titulo = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    Ficha_publicada = serializers.BooleanField()

    def validate_Titulo(self, attrs, source):
        value = attrs[source]

        if not Ficha_publicada:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Ficha no publicada")
        return attrs

    class Meta:
        model = Fichas
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `attrs['Ficha_publicada']` :

```
if not attrs['Ficha_publicada']:
    raise serializers.ValidationError("Ficha no publicada")
return attrs
```

Answer (score 6):

And for `Django rest framework 3.0` and more recent versions:

```
def validate_Titulo(self, value):
```

Answer (score 3):

For Django 1.8 you need to use a slightly different method signature.

From (<1.8)

`def validate_Titulo(self, attrs, source):`

To (1.8)

`def validate_Titulo(self, attrs, source=None):`

If you do not add the default `None` to the `source` argument in Django 1.8 you will get a TypeError exception saying:

validate_Titulo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'source'