# Django REST Framework custom fields validation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create custom validation for a model, to check that its `start_date` is before its `end_date` and it is proving near impossible.

Stuff I've tried:

- built-in Django validators: none check for this
- writing my own, like so:

  ```
  def validate_date(self):
     if self.start_date < self.end_date:
          raise serializers.ValidationError("End date must be after start date.")
  ```

That bit of code I have added to the Serializer class (and then the model), but it does not seem to get called in either location.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119672/django-rest-framework-field-level-validation-in-serializer) bit of code that might be of use, but I don't know how to integrate in my method- it seems that it would work to validate one model attribute, but I need to check between two attributes.

My model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    relation_model = models.ForeignKey(RelationModel, related_name="mymodels")
    priority = models.IntegerField(
        validators = [validators.MinValueValidator(0), validators.MaxValueValidator(100)])
    start_date = models.DateField()
end_date = models.DateField()

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        today = datetime.date.today()
        return (today >= self.start_date) and (today <= self.end_date)

    def __unicode__(self):
        ...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('relation_model', 'priority', 'start_date', 'end_date')
```

Fyi, all the other validations work!

My serializer:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    relation_model = RelationModelSerializer
    is_active = serializers.Field(source='is_active')

    def validate_date(self):
        if self.start_date > self.end_date:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("End date must be after start date.")   

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = (
            'id', 'relation_model', 'priority', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'is_active'
        )
```

My view:

```
class MyModelList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    ordering = ('priority')
```

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You should use an object wide validation (`validate()`), since `validate_date` will never be called since `date` is not a field on the serializer. [From the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation):

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate(self, data):
        """
        Check that the start is before the stop.
        """
        if data['start_date'] > data['end_date']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("finish must occur after start")
        return data
```

As suggested by Michel Sabchuk you can add the validation error to the `end_date` field:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate(self, data):
        """
        Check that the start is before the stop.
        """
        if data['start_date'] > data['end_date']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"end_date": "finish must occur after start"})
        return data
```

Another possibility is to create a validator. I created one based on the code for `UniqueTogetherValidator`:

```
from rest_framework.utils.representation import smart_repr

class DateBeforeValidator:
    """
    Validator for checking if a start date is before an end date field.
    Implementation based on `UniqueTogetherValidator` of Django Rest Framework.
    """
    message = _('{start_date_field} should be before {end_date_field}.')

    def __init__(self, start_date_field="start_date", end_date_field="end_date", message=None):
        self.start_date_field = start_date_field
        self.end_date_field = end_date_field
        self.message = message or self.message

    def __call__(self, attrs):
        if attrs[self.start_date_field] > attrs[self.end_date_field]:
            message = self.message.format(
                start_date_field=self.start_date_field,
                end_date_field=self.end_date_field,
            )
            # Replace the following line with
            #   raise serializers.ValidationError(
            #       {self.end_date_field: message},
            #       code='date_before',
            #   )
            # if you want to raise the error on the field level
            raise serializers.ValidationError(message, code='date_before')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%s(start_date_field=%s, end_date_field=%s)>' % (
            self.__class__.__name__,
            smart_repr(self.start_date_field),
            smart_repr(self.end_date_field)
        )


class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        # If your start/end date fields have another name give them as kwargs tot the
        # validator:
        #   DateBeforeValidator(
        #       start_date_field="my_start_date", 
        #       end_date_field="my_end_date",
        #   )
        validators = [DateBeforeValidator()]
```

Pre DRF 3.0 you could also add it to the clean function of a model, but this is not called anymore in DRF 3.0.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    def clean(self):
        if self.end_date < self.start_date:
            raise ValidationError("End date must be after start date.")
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem! I've decided to go with adding it to the model class, because adding it to the serializer breaks the Edit endpoint (if you only want to change one of the dates, it will cause a serializer error).

For anyone finding this post with the same question, make sure you add
    ```
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    ```
to your model file.

Comment: jadelange@ your solution worked for me for form validation, so you deserve upvote from me. I have fallen in another problem and that is not working for rest framework l. can you please explain it ?

Comment: ohh I forgot one thing to mention. If I use clean method in the model then it does not work for rest call

Comment: It is worth noting that since DRF 3.0, the model's `clean` method will not be called anymore as explained here... http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#differences-between-modelserializer-validation-and-modelform

Comment: while writing clean methods in forms I generally use cleaned_data.get() method to get the cleaned data and add a custom validation. Does the data['attr'] gets clean() before ??

Comment: @David M. - That URL is invalid now.  Here's the correct one... https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.0-announcement/

Answer (score 53):

Another answer here might be useful, regarding the situation if one chooses to override serializer's `validate()` method.

Regarding answer on [Order of Serializer Validation in Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591574/order-of-serializer-validation-in-django-rest-framework), I must say that [`serializer.validate()`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/e39d8410de26003421f7e644f9206833a3b9bbe0/rest_framework/serializers.py#L436) method is called at the end of the validation sequence. However, field's validators are called before that, in [`serializer.to_internal_value()`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/e39d8410de26003421f7e644f9206833a3b9bbe0/rest_framework/serializers.py#L374), raising `ValidationError` at the end.

This means that **custom validation errors do not stack with default ones**.

In my opinion cleanest way to achieve desired behaviour is by using [target field method](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/e39d8410de26003421f7e644f9206833a3b9bbe0/rest_framework/serializers.py#L394) validation in serializer class:

```
def validate_end_date(self, value):
    # validation process...
    return value
```

In case if you need another field value from the model, such as `start_date` in this case, you can get them (yet unvalidated, as a process is not complete) with:

```py
# `None` here can be replaced with the field's default value
start_date = self.initial_data.get('start_date')
```

Comment: Thanks but just sticking that method in the serializer does not work. What else needs to be done?

Comment: @Pithikos, well, it surely does for me and others. Do you have any specific conditions?

Comment: Is there a way to access other data of serializer from the target field method?

Comment: @Vedmant, as I recall `self` argument is the reference to Serializer instance.

Comment: @Pithikos you have to call serializer.is_valid() in your view in order to execute validation,

Answer (score 31):

jgadelange's answer worked before django rest 3 probably. If any one using the django rest framework 3* version, I think this would be helpful for that folk. one should keep validation process in model level and clean method may be the one solution. But django rest framework announcement says [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.0-announcement/) that, if someone wants to validate rest-call in model .clean method, he/she should override the serializer validate method and need to call the clean method form this serializer class by the following way

**(because doc says : clean() method will not be called as part of serializer validation)**

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   def validate(self, attrs):
     instance = MyModel(**attrs)
     instance.clean()
     return attrs
```

and model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

    def clean(self):
        if self.end_date < self.start_date:
            raise ValidationError("End date must be after start date.")
```

Comment: your documentation link is now invalid. Could you update it? Thanks!

Comment: The linked docs says "There may be some cases where you really do need to keep validation logic in the model .clean() method, and cannot instead separate it into the serializer .validate(). You can do so by explicitly instantiating a model instance in the .validate() method. Again, you really should look at properly separating the validation logic out of the model method if possible, but the above might be useful in some backwards compatibility cases, or for an easy migration path." So its not saying "Do it this way"; its saying you can do it in the model but don't, use the serializer instead.

Comment: This is NOT a proper validation for serializer.

Comment: you will have prblms if your model has relation fields

Answer (score 12):

The jgadelange and Damaged Organic's solutions are pretty interesting if you prefer a simpler solution, specially if you don't plan to reuse the validator more than once, but I would suggest an improvement: I would use the object level validator, raising a dict with the field's validation error:

```
def validate(self, data):
    ...
    if data["start_date"] > data["end_date"]:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            {"end_date": "End date must be after start date."}
        )
    ...
```

I'm taking advantage that the [ValidationError class accepts an object with the error details](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#validationerror). This way, I can emulate the same behavior of a field level validation, tying the error message with the field itself, while I can still compare the dates after each one was validated individually.

This is important to ensure that you are not comparing to an unclean start date that you would need to cast before comparison (as you would be doing if you were using self.initial_data).

Comment: I will update my answer to have the error show on the `end_date` field. I agree that would be better

Answer (score 7):

I will expand Konrad answer. I like it because its quite explicit, and also you are calling validation on other fields when we use them. So it is safer, probably will be redundant (some validations will be called twice)

First thing to note, is that if we implement like this, when we run run_validator, only validations set in validators variable will appear. So if we validate a field for example with the validate_ methods, it will not be run.

Also, I have make it inheritable, so we can reimplement the validation function and rehuse the code.

**validators.py**

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ValidationError

class OtherFieldValidator:

    #### This part is the same for all validators ####

    def __init__(self, other_field):
        self.other_field = other_field # name of parameter

    def set_context(self, serializer_field):
        self.serializer_field = serializer_field # name of field where validator is defined

    def make_validation(self,field, other_field):
        pass

    def __call__(self, value):
        field = value
        serializer = self.serializer_field.parent # serializer of model
        raw_other_field = serializer.initial_data[self.other_field] # data del otro campo

        try:
            other_field = serializer.fields[self.other_field].run_validation(raw_other_field)
        except ValidationError:
            return # if date_start is incorrect we will omit validating range

    #### Here is the only part that changes ####

        self.make_validation(field,other_field)

class EndDateValidator(OtherFieldValidator):

    def make_validation(self,field, other_field):
        date_end = field
        date_start = other_field
        if date_start and date_end and date_end < date_start:
            raise ValidationError('date cannot be')
```

So the serializer will be like this : **serializers.py**

```
# Other imports
from .validators import EndDateValidator

 def myfoo(value):                                                        
     raise ValidationError("start date error")                             

 class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):                                        
     class Meta:                                                          
         model = MyModel                                                      
         fields = '__all__'                                                                                       
         extra_kwargs = {                                                 
             'date_end': {'validators': [EndDateValidator('date_start')]},
             'date_start': {'validators': [myfoo]},                       
         }
```

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone struggling with implementing this as class-based validator on field...

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ValidationError

class EndDateValidator:
    def __init__(self, start_date_field):
        self.start_date_field = start_date_field

    def set_context(self, serializer_field):
        self.serializer_field = serializer_field

    def __call__(self, value):
        end_date = value
        serializer = self.serializer_field.parent
        raw_start_date = serializer.initial_data[self.start_date_field]

        try:
            start_date = serializer.fields[self.start_date_field].run_validation(raw_start_date)
        except ValidationError:
            return  # if start_date is incorrect we will omit validating range

        if start_date and end_date and end_date < start_date:
            raise ValidationError('{} cannot be less than {}'.format(self.serializer_field.field_name, self.start_date_field)
```

Assuming you have `start_date` and `end_date` fields in your serializer, you can then set in on `end_date` field with `validators=[EndDateValidator('start_date')]`.