# Django REST Framework Serializing One to One Models

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to convert from using Django forms to just using REST Framework serializers for the forms. My models are:

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='details', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Company Name', max_length=50, unique=True)
    info = models.CharField(verbose_name='Company Information', max_length=300, blank=True)
```

I have serializers for User, UserDetails, and Company.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', )

class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = models.UserDetails
        fields = ('user', 'date_of_birth')
        read_only_fields = ('is_verified',)

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Company
        fields = ('name', 'info')
```

When users register, they will also specify company information and will become an employee of that company. How do I go about creating a form to create all three records atomically?

Here's my attempt:

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    details = UserDetailsSerializer(label='')
    password = serializers.CharField(
        label='Password',
        style={'input_type': 'password'}
    )

    password2 = serializers.CharField(
        label='Password Confirmation',
        style={'input_type': 'password'}
    )

    company = CompanySerializer()
```

I also want a password confirmation field, which will cause the form to be invalid if it does not match. Django forms had a `clean()` method which I used to valid the data. I'm not sure if serializers do (can't find it in the doucmentation). Also, when I call the serializer's `save()` in my View class, it's asking me to implement the `create()` method for the serializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are methods for creating and updating instances in serializers

From [drf official docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) below

> If we want to be able to return complete object instances based on the validated data we need to implement one or both of the .create() and update() methods. For example:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Comment(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.content = validated_data.get('content', instance.content)
        instance.created = validated_data.get('created', instance.created)
        return instance
```

drf also have [Field-level validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) from there api docs below

> You can specify custom field-level validation by adding .validate_ methods to your Serializer subclass. These are similar to the .clean_ methods on Django forms.
>   These methods take a single argument, which is the field value that requires validation.
>   Your validate_ methods should return the validated value or raise a serializers.ValidationError. For example:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = serializers.CharField()

    def validate_title(self, value):
        """
        Check that the blog post is about Django.
        """
        if 'django' not in value.lower():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Blog post is not about Django")
        return value
```

Comment: Thanks! Follow up question: is there a way to set multiple field errors instead of raising an exception? I'm looking for a function similar to django forms `add_error() ` method.

Comment: You are welcome . I think possible follow up answer is here [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31278625/3898339)