# How to validate fields with foreign keys in serializers context?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I'm working on some validations, and I want to check whether the `requesterid` entered is referencing to a `userroleid` value of "3" from `userTable` model. If it doesn't meet the criteria, it will raise a validation error. How can I access a field from a referenced table?

What I have tried is something like `request = self.context.get("requesterid__userroleid")` but it doesn't validate correctly. Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Here's my serializers:

```
class RequestCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parts=PartSerializer(many=True) 
    class Meta: model = requestTable 
    fields = ['rid', 'requesterid', (...)]
    
    def create(self, validated_data): 
        (...)
    
    def validate(self, data): 
    request = self.context.get("requesterid__userroleid") #how to access userroleid? if request == 3: 
        return data
    raise serializers.ValidationError("Sorry! Your role has no permission to create a request.")
```

Here's my views:

class RequestListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
queryset = requestTable.objects.all()
serializer_class = RequestCreateSerializer

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
(...)

def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):

    serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
    kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
    return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)    

def get_serializer_context(self):
    return {
        'request': self.request,
        'format': self.format_kwarg,
        'view': self
    }
```

Here's my models:

```
class requestTable(models.Model):
rid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)    
requesterid =  models.ForeignKey(userTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
(...)

class userTable(models.Model):
userid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default = uuid.uuid4, editable=False) userroleid = models.ForeignKey(roleTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class roleTable(models.Model):
roleid = models.IntegerField(null=False, primary_key=True)
role = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django REST Framework custom fields validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278418/django-rest-framework-custom-fields-validation)

Comment: It's okay now @MikeJones! thanks! but yes! that's how I did it, with proper foreign key referencing

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using this code:

```
def validate(self, data):
    if data['requesterid'].userroleid_id != 3:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Sorry! You entered a user with no requester permissions.")
    return data
```